# Storing \r\n in MySQL and Retrieving and Writing to Text File via PHP

Tags: php, sql, carriage-return

I have a dataset which needs to be imported into an application via CSV. The problem I have is that the \r\n characters used by the program to denote a new line, aren't being exported.

MySQL recognises that they're in the database, but PHP can't seem to export them into the text file, it executes them instead. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I'm a bit lost.

The Variable:

```
$elec_desc = "Value Used " . $row['item_no'] . " From " . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($readings[3])) . " to " . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($readings[1])) . '\\r\\n' . "Prev Reading " . $readings[2] . " QTY Type    New Reading " . $readings[0] . " QTY Type " . '\\r\\n' . "Total Usage " . $totalused . " QTY Type " . '\\r\\n' . "Price per QTY Type \$$usagefee";
```

Prepared statements aren't used at this point, I was planning to modify things later once I had everything working correctly.

The export:

```
        if ($res[$price] != 0.00){
            $string_to_push = $res['inv_no'] . "," . $res['inv_date'] . "," . $sres['name'] . "," . $res[$acc] . "," . $res[$desc] . "," . $res[$gst] . "," . round((($res[$price]/11)*10),2) . "," . round(($res[$price]/11),2) . ",E";
            array_push($array_of_invs, $string_to_push);

        } else {
            $i = 11;
        }
    }
}

$prevsub = "IV000000";

for($inc=0;$inc<sizeof($array_of_invs);$inc++){
    $file_name = $curr_date . "_inv_export.txt";
    $string = $array_of_invs[$inc];

    if ($prevsub == substr($string,0,8)){
        $myfile = file_put_contents($file_name, $string.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    } else {
        $myfile = file_put_contents($file_name, PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        $myfile = file_put_contents($file_name, ($string.PHP_EOL) , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }

    $prevsub = substr($string,0,8);
}
```

Comment: Please post the PHP code and a sample of the original string with a sample of the incorrect output PHP is producing.

Comment: What do you mean by "it executes them"? If you're storing actual escape sequences, they won't be executed by PHP. It only recognizes escape sequences in literals. I suspect you're really storing the CR and LF characters in the DB, not the escape sequences. Remember, MySQL parses them as escape sequences when you `INSERT`, it doesn't save them literally.

Comment: You would need to write `'\\r\\n'` when inserting to store them literally.

Comment: @Barmar I have written them as \\r\\n. It stores them fine in MySQL. When generating the export text file, it actually creates new lines in the text file rather than showing the carriage returns.

Comment: You need to show your code so we can see how this is happening.

Comment: Did you write `\\r\\n` in a PHP variable or a MySQL literal? If it's a PHP variable, did you use a prepared statement or an escaping function when you stored it into the DB? There's so many ways that the escape sequence can be executed when doing the storing, but it's not going to happen when you retrieve and export.

Comment: Code is now in primary post

Comment: You still haven't shown how you're storing the string into the DB. If you call `mysqli_real_escape_string()` it should properly escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the solution was simple enough. Escaping them once wasn't enough since they were contained within a variable, the answer was to escape them twice. Never thought to go down that road since I thought adding a third slash in would just execute them.

```
 \\\r\\\n
```

^ Seemed to do the trick as they stored correctly in MySQL and exported correctly.

Comment: I think the real problem is you didn't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or a prepared statement when you stored into the DB.